# Please remember to vote

Tags: discussion

Voting on Stack Exchange sites does a number of things. It rewards the content that we like to see when we upvote. It also signals trust, the more someone is upvoted, the more powers (muahahahahahaha!) on the stackexchange site they get.

If we want this site to be successful, those of us that use it on a regular basis need to be upvoting the content we really like and downvoting what we dislike. This gets newer users more involved, and helps spread  the responsibility of keeping the site up and running.

So please, remember to vote.  It does a site good.

Comment: +1 - Could not agree more.

Comment: `...upvoting the content we really like and downvoting what we dislike`. Amen!

Comment: I wish people would up vote more interesting questions and not just "identify" questions...

Comment: +1 and I fully admit I need to do more. Just because people have high rep doesn't mean they're voting. This will definitely be my resolution for this year on the site.

Comment: +1 because this is meta. Also, because voting buttons are shiny.

Answer (score 29):

I believe one of the main reasons we are stuck in beta is because we do not have any users above 20k reputation.

We need users with this much in order to help whoever gets selected as moderators to police the site.

So whether it be upvoting another great answer by @Nobby or down-voting my latest ramblings, let your opinion be heard, you have 40 of these things to give out each day,

### ***USE THEM***

Comment: You think my answers are great? I can die happy.

Comment: A good thing to remember is to reward the question *and* the answer(s) you find useful/helpful. A lot of people seem to forget they can vote for both (myself included sometimes!) :)

Answer (score 13):

While voting on the main site is an important concern we need to work at, please also don't forget to vote in meta.

Votes are the only thing how meta can reach reasonable conclusions and meta activity isn't particularly high in the first place, so it needs each and every vote it can get, at least from the select few who engage in meta and have built opinions about its topics. If you stumble across a meta discussion that you have an opinion to, then please don't refrain from upvoting ideas you agree with and downvoting ideas you disagree with.

Answer (score 7):

As everyone has already said that voting is important. I will like to add that voting good questions is as important as voting answers.

P.S. I would have preffered it as comment. However, very few people read comments

Comment: It's good as an answer anyway as it adresses a very important point. As much as people don't like to vote on answers, they even less like to vote on questions. This is a natural consequence of answers being more directly "helpful" and is the reason that SE tells you to actually vote on questions if you haven't done so for quite some time. It is great that you noticed this and are concerned about it.